# Compiler error while converting array to list?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, type-conversion

I am trying to transform an array of Cause to an `ArrayList` of Cause and i get this compiler error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<Cause> to Cause[]
```

This is the implementation:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MyException extends Exception

    private List<Cause> causes;

    public MyException(Cause... causes) {
        causes = new ArrayList<Cause>(Arrays.asList(causes));
    }

}
```

How can I convert that causes that I am receiving as a parameter to the List member? (I don't want to change parameter's type). Do you have any idea?

Comment: In think the error is in this portion - `(Arrays.asList(causes))`.

Comment: What does `causes` refer to in your constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusing error is due to name shadowing (i.e. using the same name for two different things in the same scope); you have `causes` as a field of your class, and also as a parameter to the constructor. Rename it as shown and all is well:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {

    private List<Cause> causes;

    public MyException(Cause... cs) {
        causes = new ArrayList<Cause>(Arrays.asList(cs));
    }
}
```

**Update**: as the comments correctly point out, you commonly get around this problem by making it explicit to the compiler when you are referring to the field, using `this`:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {

    private List<Cause> causes;

    public MyException(Cause... causes) {
        this.causes = new ArrayList<Cause>(Arrays.asList(causes));
    }
}
```

Comment: Or use the common pattern `this.causes = ...` to initialize the member.

Comment: Although your answer is helpful, why are your Lists of String?

Comment: Good point, I changed them to String when I was testing the code; will edit the answer.

Answer (score 7):

The left hand side of the assignment in your constructor refers the parameter, not to the field. (Also there's a `{` missing). You can fix this by adding `this.`:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {

    private List<Cause> causes;

    public MyException(Cause... causes) {
        this.causes = new ArrayList<Cause>(Arrays.asList(causes));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The parameter `String... causes` is the same as `causes[]`.  If you want to convert it to a list you need to declare a new variable:

```
  List<Cause> causesList = Arrays.asList(causes);
```

Or simply explicitly reference your member class variable

```
   this.causes = Arrays.asList(causes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `cause` as `List<Cause>` -

```
private List<Cause> causes;
```

and trying to convert `causes` (which is an `arrayList` already) to an array at here -

```
causes = new ArrayList<Cause>(Arrays.asList(causes));
```

Try to change either of `causes` from declaration or from method parameter.